How can I install java Swing in 2024 (for eclipse)?
In the past I have made graphical interfaces with Java Swing. On my new computer I have tried to install java Swing but I have not found how to do it. I have searched in eclipse marketplace but it doesn't exist, I have tried it in Help/Install new software but I cannot find a url from which to download.
Does anyone know how it can be installed currently?
Thank you
I tried to install it from eclipse marketplace and from url

You don't install Swing. It's part of the JDK. So if anything, you install a JDK

What are you trying to do exactly?

do you eventually mean some plugin/add-on for Eclipse to help design/develop GUIs, something like WindowBuilder?

I think I have not explained well. I want to install the swing/window builder module for eclipse so I can use the Wizard and create a New JFrame and see the elements graphically

I want to install the swing/window builder module for eclipse OK, that's somewhat different. That's separate software - a GUI builder. That won't be supported here as such. For one thing drag-drop builders have a tendency to produce unmaintainable code

Ooooh I think I found it https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/windowbuilder/help

you found it ?? seems to be the same add-on I linked to in my first comment

Swing built into Java
Java 2 through today’s Java 22 all include Swing.
Swing has always been defined as part of Java SE. Every implementation of the Java Specifications include all the classes necessary to write and run Swing apps.
Swing is nowadays in maintenance-mode, receiving bug fixes. No further feature work is being done.
Swing is fully supported as an essential part of Java. Nevertheless, you may want to explore alternatives:

For desktop & mobile apps, I suggest JavaFX, now implemented as OpenJFX.
For web apps written in pure Java, I suggest Vaadin Flow framework. The client-side HTML, CSS, and JavaScript is auto-generated on-the-fly.


To deploy your Java app you must include an implementation of the Java specifications, a JDK/JRE. You can choose from any of several vendors. These vendors include: Azul Systems, Adoptium of the Eclipse Foundation, BellSoft, Microsoft, Oracle, SAP, Red Hat, IBM, Amazon, and more. All of these JDK products come with the necessary Swing classes.
You may find the jlink tool helpful in bundling a JVM within your app. If your app is modularized, you can even use jlink to strip down the bundled JVM to only include the parts your app actually uses.
You may find the jpackage tool useful in producing the final app artifact.

For more info:

Blog post: Java Client Roadmap Updates by Donald Smith, Vice President of Product Management at Oracle.
White paper: Java Client Roadmap Update by Oracle, 2020-05.


I need this Swing window Builder Wizard in order to create Jframe and elements graphically
I think I found it I think I found it  Swing elements Wizard
